# OBJFILELOADER - pygame

Tags: opengl, pygame, objloader

So I tried running [the code](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/OBJFileLoader) but it gives list out of index range error. I changed the index from 1 to 0, but the screen only pops up black. How could I change the code to make it work?

Comment: Please post the complete error message/stack trace.

Comment: obj = OBJ(sys.argv[1],"suzzane.mtl")

IndexError: list index out of range

I changed the index to 0 but then only a black screen pops up.

Comment: Just copy everything you see under "Traceback (most recent call last):" and add that to your post.

Comment: It looks like you're instantiating `OBJ` incorrectly. The first argument should be the filename (I think the .obj file). The second argument is `swapyz` (should be a boolean). So if the filename is `suzzane.obj`, you should instantiate `OBJ` in this way: `obj = OBJ('suzzane.obj')`.

Comment: The script seems to be written in Python 2 and there are some things that have to be updated for Python 3, e.g. `v = list(map(float, values[1:4]))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to pass the filename/path of the .obj file to the `OBJ` class:

```
obj = OBJ('suzzane.obj')
```

---

Also, the script was written in Python 2 and if you want to use it with Python 3, you have to update a few things.

Change this line,

```
raise ValueError, "mtl file doesn't start with newmtl stmt"
```

to:

```
raise ValueError("mtl file doesn't start with newmtl stmt")
```

And all the `map` iterators have to be turned into lists:

```
mtl[values[0]] = map(float, values[1:])
# Just call `list()`.
mtl[values[0]] = list(map(float, values[1:]))
```

Comment: It worked! I realized the first change, but totally forgot about list change.

Answer (score -1):

Try generating wavefront(.obj) file and make sure to put the `suzzane.obj` and `suzzane.mtl` file on one directory with your code,

And instead of:

> Sys.arg[0]

Use:

> obj = OBJ('suzzane.obj')