# Error in OBJFileLoader

Tags: python, pygame, blender, pyopengl, objloader

There's error in OBJFILELOADER.py file from the link - https://www.pygame.org/wiki/OBJFileLoader .
I think there's python2 to python3 version error, however I tried changing the *raise ValueError* thing and used obj as *obj=(filename)*

But still there's lots of errors.

I took the .obj file from blender, I don't think that's the issue. 
Can anyone tell me the exact objfileloader for **Python3**

Error -

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/warted/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenGL/latebind.py", line 41, in __call__
    return self._finalCall( *args, **named )
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 28, in <module>
    obj = OBJ('robotbase.obj')
  File "/home/warted/COMMAND CENTRE/SEDS/GUI/Simulate/objloader.py", line 97, in __init__
    glNormal3fv(self.normals[normals[i] - 1])
  File "/home/warted/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenGL/latebind.py", line 45, in __call__
    return self._finalCall( *args, **named )
  File "/home/warted/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenGL/wrapper.py", line 677, in wrapperCall
    pyArgs = tuple( calculate_pyArgs( args ))
  File "/home/warted/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenGL/wrapper.py", line 438, in calculate_pyArgs
    yield converter(args[index], self, args)
  File "/home/warted/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenGL/arrays/arrayhelpers.py", line 112, in asArraySize
    handler = typ.getHandler( incoming )
  File "/home/warted/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenGL/arrays/arraydatatype.py", line 53, in __call__
    typ.__module__, type.__name__, repr(value)[:50]
TypeError: ('No array-type handler for type builtins.type (value: <map object at 0x7f6bf0f8f4a8>) registered', <function asArrayTypeSize.<locals>.asArraySize at 0x7f6c01d6a620>)
```

Comment: always put full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot)

Comment: BTW: did you use program `2to3` to convert code from Python 2 to Python 3 ? You should have `2to3` installed with Python 3.

Comment: if you think that there is problem with `raise` then did you check in Python 3 documentation how to use `raise` ?

Comment: `obj=(filename)` ??? what do you try to do ? what result do you expect ?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46611564/6220679).

Comment: @furas I tried this `2to3` it changed objloader.py file but still the problem is not corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just seem to assign the filename to the variable `obj`.

Instead you have to create an instance of the `OBJ` class and pass the file/path name:

```
obj = OBJ(filename)
```

To port the script to Python 3 check out the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46611564/6220679).

---

Try this updated version:

```
import pygame
from OpenGL.GL import *

def MTL(filename):
    contents = {}
    mtl = None
    for line in open(filename, "r"):
        if line.startswith('#'): continue
        values = line.split()
        if not values: continue
        if values[0] == 'newmtl':
            mtl = contents[values[1]] = {}
        elif mtl is None:
            raise ValueError("mtl file doesn't start with newmtl stmt")
        elif values[0] == 'map_Kd':
            # load the texture referred to by this declaration
            mtl[values[0]] = values[1]
            surf = pygame.image.load(mtl['map_Kd'])
            image = pygame.image.tostring(surf, 'RGBA', 1)
            ix, iy = surf.get_rect().size
            texid = mtl['texture_Kd'] = glGenTextures(1)
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texid)
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
                GL_LINEAR)
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
                GL_LINEAR)
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, ix, iy, 0, GL_RGBA,
                GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image)
        else:
            mtl[values[0]] = list(map(float, values[1:]))
    return contents

class OBJ:
    def __init__(self, filename, swapyz=False):
        """Loads a Wavefront OBJ file. """
        self.vertices = []
        self.normals = []
        self.texcoords = []
        self.faces = []

        material = None
        for line in open(filename, "r"):
            if line.startswith('#'): continue
            values = line.split()
            if not values: continue
            if values[0] == 'v':
                v = list(map(float, values[1:4]))
                if swapyz:
                    v = v[0], v[2], v[1]
                self.vertices.append(v)
            elif values[0] == 'vn':
                v = list(map(float, values[1:4]))
                if swapyz:
                    v = v[0], v[2], v[1]
                self.normals.append(v)
            elif values[0] == 'vt':
                self.texcoords.append(list(map(float, values[1:3])))
            elif values[0] in ('usemtl', 'usemat'):
                material = values[1]
            elif values[0] == 'mtllib':
                self.mtl = MTL(values[1])
            elif values[0] == 'f':
                face = []
                texcoords = []
                norms = []
                for v in values[1:]:
                    w = v.split('/')
                    face.append(int(w[0]))
                    if len(w) >= 2 and len(w[1]) > 0:
                        texcoords.append(int(w[1]))
                    else:
                        texcoords.append(0)
                    if len(w) >= 3 and len(w[2]) > 0:
                        norms.append(int(w[2]))
                    else:
                        norms.append(0)
                self.faces.append((face, norms, texcoords, material))

        self.gl_list = glGenLists(1)
        glNewList(self.gl_list, GL_COMPILE)
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
        glFrontFace(GL_CCW)
        for face in self.faces:
            vertices, normals, texture_coords, material = face

            mtl = self.mtl[material]
            if 'texture_Kd' in mtl:
                # use diffuse texmap
                glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mtl['texture_Kd'])
            else:
                # just use diffuse colour
                glColor(*mtl['Kd'])

            glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
            for i in range(len(vertices)):
                if normals[i] > 0:
                    glNormal3fv(self.normals[normals[i] - 1])
                if texture_coords[i] > 0:
                    glTexCoord2fv(self.texcoords[texture_coords[i] - 1])
                glVertex3fv(self.vertices[vertices[i] - 1])
            glEnd()
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
        glEndList()
```

Comment: I already tried this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46609928/objfileloader-pygame/46611564#46611564), but there's same error.

Comment: Thanks @skrx The updated version helped. It ran. Thankyou. :)

Comment: @skrx you could send it to pygame.org or put on GitHub