# Is there a way to change the location and size of an imported .obj file in Pygame?

Tags: python, opengl, pygame, pyopengl, .obj

I created an .obj file using blender and loaded into Pygame using the OBJfileloader as sugested by skrx in:
[Error in OBJFileLoader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47660370/error-in-objfileloader)

Is there an easy way to change the location, height and width of the imported .obj file after importing it into Pygame? As an example, if you create a tree.obj file, to be able to place that same tree in different places with different sizes?

Following the code below, maybe something like:

```py
object_obj = OBJ("Tree.obj", swapyz=False)

object_obj.setX = 0

object_obj.setWidth = 3

object_obj.setHeight =10
```

Or by sending extra parameters to the obj loader, changing the vertices?

OBJ Loader:

```
import pygame
from OpenGL.GL import *

def MTL(filename):
    filename = 'OBJ/'+filename
    contents = {}
    mtl = None
    for line in open(filename, "r"):
        if line.startswith('#'): continue
        values = line.split()
        if not values: continue
        if values[0] == 'newmtl':
            mtl = contents[values[1]] = {}
        elif mtl is None:
            raise ValueError("mtl file doesn't start with newmtl stmt")
        elif values[0] == 'map_Kd':
            # load the texture referred to by this declaration
            mtl[values[0]] = values[1]
            surf = pygame.image.load(mtl['map_Kd'])
            image = pygame.image.tostring(surf, 'RGBA', 1)
            ix, iy = surf.get_rect().size
            texid = mtl['texture_Kd'] = glGenTextures(1)
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texid)
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
                GL_LINEAR)
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
                GL_LINEAR)
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, ix, iy, 0, GL_RGBA,
                GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image)
        else:
            mtl[values[0]] = list(map(float, values[1:]))
    return contents

class OBJ:
    def __init__(self, filename, swapyz=False):
        """Loads a Wavefront OBJ file. """
        self.vertices = []
        self.normals = []
        self.texcoords = []
        self.faces = []

        material = None
        for line in open(filename, "r"):
            if line.startswith('#'): continue
            values = line.split()
            if not values: continue
            if values[0] == 'v':
                v = list(map(float, values[1:4]))
                if swapyz:
                    v = v[0], v[2], v[1]
                self.vertices.append(v)
            elif values[0] == 'vn':
                v = list(map(float, values[1:4]))
                if swapyz:
                    v = v[0], v[2], v[1]
                self.normals.append(v)
            elif values[0] == 'vt':
                self.texcoords.append(list(map(float, values[1:3])))
            elif values[0] in ('usemtl', 'usemat'):
                material = values[1]
            elif values[0] == 'mtllib':
                self.mtl = MTL(values[1])
            elif values[0] == 'f':
                face = []
                texcoords = []
                norms = []
                for v in values[1:]:
                    w = v.split('/')
                    face.append(int(w[0]))
                    if len(w) >= 2 and len(w[1]) > 0:
                        texcoords.append(int(w[1]))
                    else:
                        texcoords.append(0)
                    if len(w) >= 3 and len(w[2]) > 0:
                        norms.append(int(w[2]))
                    else:
                        norms.append(0)
                self.faces.append((face, norms, texcoords, material))

        self.gl_list = glGenLists(1)
        glNewList(self.gl_list, GL_COMPILE)
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
        glFrontFace(GL_CCW)
        for face in self.faces:
            vertices, normals, texture_coords, material = face

            mtl = self.mtl[material]
            if 'texture_Kd' in mtl:
                # use diffuse texmap
                glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mtl['texture_Kd'])
            else:
                # just use diffuse colour
                glColor(*mtl['Kd'])

            glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
            for i in range(len(vertices)):
                if normals[i] > 0:
                    glNormal3fv(self.normals[normals[i] - 1])
                if texture_coords[i] > 0:
                    glTexCoord2fv(self.texcoords[texture_coords[i] - 1])
                glVertex3fv(self.vertices[vertices[i] - 1])
            glEnd()
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
        glEndList()
```

Displaying .OBJ file in Pygame:

```
# Basic OBJ file viewer. needs objloader from:
#  http://www.pygame.org/wiki/OBJFileLoader
# LMB + move: rotate
# RMB + move: pan
# Scroll wheel: zoom in/out
import sys, pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from pygame.constants import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *

# IMPORT OBJECT LOADER
from OBJ_Loader import *

pygame.init()
viewport = (800,600)
hx = viewport[0]/2
hy = viewport[1]/2
srf = pygame.display.set_mode(viewport, OPENGL | DOUBLEBUF)

glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION,  (-40, 200, 100, 0.0))
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, (0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0))
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0))
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0)
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL)
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH)           # most obj files expect to be smooth-shaded

# LOAD OBJECT AFTER PYGAME INIT
object_obj = OBJ("Tree.obj", swapyz=False)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
glLoadIdentity()
width, height = viewport
gluPerspective(90, 1, 0.001, 1000.0)
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)

rx, ry = (0,0)
tx, ty = (0,0)
zpos = 1
rotate = move = False
while 1:
    clock.tick(30)
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_ESCAPE:
            sys.exit()
        elif e.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if e.button == 4: zpos = max(1, zpos-1)
            elif e.button == 5: zpos += 1
            elif e.button == 1: rotate = True
            elif e.button == 3: move = True
        elif e.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            if e.button == 1: rotate = False
            elif e.button == 3: move = False
        elif e.type == MOUSEMOTION:
            i, j = e.rel
            if rotate:
                rx += i
                ry += j
            if move:
                tx += i
                ty -= j

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    glLoadIdentity()

    # RENDER OBJECT
    glTranslate(tx/20., ty/20., - zpos)
    glRotate(ry, 1, 0, 0)
    glRotate(rx, 0, 1, 0)
    glCallList(obj.gl_list)


    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Do not change the vertex coordinates! Use [`glTranslate`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTranslate.xml) and [`glScale`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glScale.xml) to define a model transformation!

Comment: I also modified the OBJ class to allow transparency. glColor(*mtl['Kd']) to glColor4f(*mtl['Kd'], *mtl['d']) and then enable alpha in pygame.init: glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/pygame-opengl-wavefront-obj](https://replit.com/@Rabbid76/pygame-opengl-wavefront-obj#main.py)</kbd>

Do not change the vertex coordinates. Use [`glTranslate`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTranslate.xml) and [`glScale`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glScale.xml) to define a model transformation.

Compute the [Axis Aligned Bounding Box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_volume), when the vertex coordinates are read:

```py
class OBJ:
    def __init__(self, filename, swapyz=False):
        """Loads a Wavefront OBJ file. """
        self.vertices = []
        self.normals = []
        self.texcoords = []
        self.faces = []

        self.min_v = [float("inf"), float("inf"), float("inf")]
        self.max_v = [-float("inf"), -float("inf"), -float("inf")]

        material = None
        for line in open(filename, "r"):
            if line.startswith('#'): continue
            values = line.split()
            if not values: continue
            if values[0] == 'v':
                v = list(map(float, values[1:4]))
                if swapyz:
                    v = v[0], v[2], v[1]

                for i in range(3):
                    self.min_v[i] = min(self.min_v[i], v[i])
                    self.max_v[i] = max(self.max_v[i], v[i])

                self.vertices.append(v)
            # [...]

        self.size = [self.max_v[i]-self.min_v[i] for i in range(3)]
        # [...]
```

Scale and translate the object when it is drawn. Use [`glPushMatrix` / `glPopMatrix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glPushMatrix.xml) to save and restore the current matrix before and after the transformations:

```py
# RENDER OBJECT
glTranslate(tx/20., ty/20., - zpos)
glRotate(ry, 1, 0, 0)
glRotate(rx, 0, 1, 0)

pos = [0, 0, -5]
size = [3, 3, 10]
scale = [size[i]/obj.size[i] for i in range(3)]

glPushMatrix()
glTranslate(*pos)
glScale(*scale)
glCallList(obj.gl_list)
glPopMatrix()
```

Alternatively that can be done in the display list, too:

```py
self.gl_list = glGenLists(1)
glNewList(self.gl_list, GL_COMPILE)
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
glFrontFace(GL_CCW)

glPushMatrix()
glTranslate(*pos)
glScale(*scale)

for face in self.faces:
    vertices, normals, texture_coords, material = face
    # [...]
    
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)

glPopMatrix()
glEndList()
```